# how to escape qutoes in ssh command and gawk

Tags: unix, awk, ssh

I am trying to read a remote file using ssh with gawk command, but I am failing with quotes issue.

```
ssh <HOST> 'gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' "<File name>" | wc -l'
```

I appreciate if anyone help to resolve this.

Comment: You can't nest single quotes inside a single-quoted string. Use `"..."` (escaping dollar signs, double quotes, and backslashes as necessary), or use `$'...'` (escaping single quotes and backslashes as necessary). Or, punt on the issue by copying a script to the remote host and executing it.

Comment: I am bit confused. can you please be specific o mention in command @chepner.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=unix+ssh+command+quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'gawk -v RS='"'  '...` is not a string that contains `RS='"'`. It's equivalent to

```
gawk -v RS="'  '...
```

The shell doesn't know that you want the entire string between the first and last `'` should be treated literally; it reads from the first `'` until the *next* `'`, then continues parsing.

Further, there's no way to quote a single quote inside `'...'`, as the backslash itself is taken literally. `'\''` is not a single `'`; it's `'` and `\`.

If you are using `bash` or a shell with a similar extension, you can use ANSI-style quoting. You'll have to ensure that all literal `'` and `'\` are escaped.

```
# Should be correct, not not tested
ssh <HOST> $'gawk -v RS=\'"\' \'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }\' "<File name>" | wc -l'
```

Or you can use `"..."` as the outer quotes, and ensure all literal `$` and `"` are escaped (as well as any `\` that would otherwise be treated as an escape character).

```
# Should be correct, not not tested
ssh <HOST> "gawk -v RS='\"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, \"\") } { printf(\"%s%s\", \$0, RT) }" "<File name>" | wc -l'
```

My preference would be to avoid the problem by putting your code in a script

```
#!/bin/sh
gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' "<File name>" | wc -l
```

copying that to the remote host

```
scp <HOST>:\~/myscript
```

and executing it

```
ssh <HOST> 'sh myscript'
```